# How to know when a jar need desugaring (for d8.bat)

Tags: android, android-studio, jar, dex, android-d8

How to know when a jar need desugaring? because `d8.bat` have a parameter --no-desugaring and i want to know when I can use it

> **--no-desugaring**: 
>   Disables Java 8 language features. Use this flag only if you don't
>   intend to compile Java bytecode that uses Java 8 language features.

Comment: Since the answer is already in the question, it is hard to guess what you are actually asking.

Comment: @henry. If I don't do --no-desugaring I need to give the class_path. so i want to know if I can safely do --no-desugaring instead of giving the class_path

Comment: It depends if Java 8 language features are used or not.

Comment: @Henry yes and how to check this? this was the question :)

Comment: I don't think you can easily check this if you don't already know. In doubt, you can always leave out the flag (or try with it and see if it works).

Comment: @Henry. but without --no-desugaring its extremely complicate because I need to set up the --classpath and i have many problems with this :( this why i want to remove --no-desugaring only when no other choice